# Entity Framework Core / Value Conversion "InvalidCastException" boolean to int

Tags: c#, db2, entity-framework-core

i have a little bit of trouble with my EF Core about the value conversion from bool to int.

The background is that I'm using IBM's DB2 as my database and the older versions don't support the BIT type, so I have to use something else to simulate a boolean. In my case I just wan't to use 1 and 0.

I want to do this with the EF Core Value Conversion.
My Converter class:

```
var myconverter = new ValueConverter<bool, int>(x => x ? 1 : 0, x => x == 1);
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b => {
      b.Property(p => p.EmailConfirmed).HasConversion(myconverter);
});
```

So, the boolean is my model type (TModel) and the int the database type (TProvider).

After executing this simple line of code:

```
var user = identityContext.Users.First();
```

I get the error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'.

And I have no idea why. An insert works fine and the proptery is stored with the right value (1/0) but the select part breaks.

The use of the inbuilt class `BoolToZeroOneConverter<int>` results in the same error.

EF Core is up to 2.1.1

Am I missing something?
Thank's for your help.

**UPDATE**
ApplicationUser inherits "IdentityUser"

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{

    public IdentityUser();

    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    public virtual string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }

    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }

    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }

    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to specify a value converter for **all** of the `bool` in your model?

Comment: Yes. But I excluded a lot of the props and just working with the EmailConfirmed boolean. And it breaks there.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using for the other bools that are working?

Comment: None of the bools is working. I think this is a general problem with my ef core.

Comment: Recently faced similar issue. Run several tests with different scenarios, and it seems that ValueConverters configured in OnModelCreating() are never get called if EF uses IBM provider. Run same scenarios with MS SQL - everything was working as expected

Comment: This appears to still be an issue. Does anyone have a solution, other than making the properties into integers?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and the only thing that worked was to disable the value conversion and to create our own properties with the same name but the expected type, the compiler throws a warning but it was the only way we made it work.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {

    //Hack: Used as a workaround with DB2's data types
    public int LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

}
```